# Table access vs function call + conditional determination: which is faster?

Tags: optimization, lua, lua-table, lookup-tables, function-call

I need to check if a particular string is one of a set of predetermined strings.

Two methods to do it came to my mind: setting up a table to return true on a particular value

```
local isParticular = {
    [string1] = true,
    [string2] = true
}

print(isParticular[string1]) -- true
print(isParticular[randomString]) -- nil -> false
```

Or setting a function to check it with a conditional determination

```
function isParticular(s)
    return s == string1 or s == string2
end

print(isParticular(string1)) -- true
print(isParticular(randomString)) -- false
```

From what I understand the table method would take the same time for both any of the particular strings and for different strings, while the function call because of short-circuit evaluation will take less time for `string1` and more time for `string2` and `randomString`.

Also, both the function call and the table access are known for causing a little overhead, but maybe the short-circuit evaluation can make the difference (in being slower I think, especially considered I have more than 2 particular strings and that most of the times the string won't match any of them).

So what method should I use?

Comment: There is only one way to be sure: Profile both! I doubt you'll see a difference however: if you are considering using `or` chaining, that tells me you don't have too many items you need to check, so no need to worry about scaling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hash-table lookup would outperform your functional lookup for a large dataset. So, go with the first method:

```
local isParticular = {
    string1 = true,
    string2 = true
}

print(isParticular[string1]) -- true
print(isParticular[randomString]) -- nil -> false
```

Comment: Just what I thought! Thanks for confirmation.